# Python Recursive operation

Tags: python, recursion, math

```
main_program = True


def program():
    print('Hello user, please enter a value to choose an option')
    print('select 1 to find the sum of two number')
    print('select 2 to find the product two number')
    print('select 3 to raise a number to a power')
    print('4 to find the reminder two number')
    print('select q for exit')

    choice = input('human enter a value: ')

    global main_program
    while main_program:
        if(choice == '1'):
            sum_of_numbers()

        elif(choice == '2'):
            product_of_numbers(*get_information())

        elif(choice == '3'):
            esponent_of_numbers(*get_information())

        elif(choice == '4'):
            modulo_of_numbers(*get_information())

        elif(choice == 'q'):
            print('program terminated')
            main_program = False
        else:
            print('wrong value entered')


def get_information():
    while True:
        try:
            x = float(input('human enter a value: '))
            y = float(input('human enter second value: '))
            return x, y
        except ValueError:
            print('my processors cannot understand the inputs')


def sum_of_numbers():
    x, y = get_information()
    sum = x + y
    print(sum)
    program()


def product_of_numbers(x, y):
    if(x < y):
        print(product_of_numbers(y, x))
        program()
    if(x == 0):
        print(0)
        program()
    else:
        print(x + product_of_numbers(x, y-1))
        program()


def esponent_of_numbers(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        print(1)
        program()
    elif y % 2 == 0:
        print(esponent_of_numbers(x, y / 2)**2)
        program()
    else:
        print(x * esponent_of_numbers(x, y-1))
        program()


def modulo_of_numbers(x, y):
    if x < y:
        print(x)
    print(modulo_of_numbers(x - y, y))
    program()


program()
```

Please I need your help. I spend hours trying to figure out the problem in these functions.
My teacher wants me to use a recursive operation given 2 numbers.
The problem is that every time I start the program and I initialize the functions I got this error.
"RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"
I am not using bit numbers and I am following the code found in other answers here in StackOverflow regarding the same argument.
So I guess I really do not grasp the concept of this problem:

If the user enters "1" at the main menu:
The user should be prompted to enter two numbers, and the summation (addition) of
the two numbers will be printed to screen.
To calculate this value, you should create a function with the following signature
where x and y can be integer or float type, that returns the answer: sum(x,y).
If the user enters "2" at the main menu:
The user should be prompted to enter two positive numbers x and y, and the product
of the two numbers will be printed to screen. The product of two numbers can be
expressed as repeated addition operations. For example, 5*4 = 20; this can be
calculated in an alternative way as (5+5+5+5) = 20.
To calculate this value, you should create a function with the following signature
where x is an int or float, and y is an int, returning the answer: prod(x,y).
If the user enters "3" at the main menu:
The user should be prompted to enter two positive numbers, x and y. The
value xyxy should then be printed to screen. The raising of x to the power of y, can
be expressed as repeated multiplications. For example,53=12553=125; this can be
alternatively expressed as 5*5*5=125.
To calculate this value, you should create a function with the following signature
where x Is an integer, and y is an integer, that returns the answer: exp(x,y).
If the user enters “4” at the main menu:
The user should be prompted to enter two positive numbers, x and y. The value should then be printed to screen. The modulo of x and y gives the remainder
after ⌊xy⌋⌊xy⌋ ,  and can be expressed as repeated subtractions. For example, 5
mod 2 = 1; this can be alternatively expressed as 5-2-2=1.
To calculate this value, you should create a function with the following signature

Comment: What is your *question*?

Comment: the first function works. for the other three when they get the value from the get_information return "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" I do not really know why this is happening

Comment: All of your functions call other functions repeatedly. It looks like in most cases, your functions never return, which means they'll constantly eat up memory until your program crashes. Instead of calling `program` again to return to it, you should just let the function end.

Comment: Although that won't be the immediate problem. `modulo_of_numbers` calls itself infinitely.

Comment: thank you for this, the thing is that even before I add the program function to return to it the other functions were broke. My key goal is to return some kind of value from them, not that silly error.

Comment: You'll need to check the trace of the error to see what function is calling itself forever. `modulo_of_numbers` is one, and there may be others. Once you know which function is calling itself repeatedly, you can debug to find out why.

Comment: yes I know modulo of numbers is the worst function of them I was tired and I did not give to it enough attention. Why the product of numbers returns that error for example????

Comment: That function only doesn't call itself if `x == 0` is true, so that must never be true. Print out values of `x` to see what's going on leading up to the crash.

Comment: I removed all the other functions and kept product of numbers just to reduce the error possibility, but that function returns constantly the same error without giving me any chance to debug it.

Comment: You need to put the `print` before the recursive calls or they'll never be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some improvements I found in your original code:

1. **(Main cause of the error)** You didn't specify when the loop should stop. For example, in the product of the two numbers, `print(x + product_of_numbers(x, y-1))` actually keeps going infinitly as you didn't tell the loop to stop at a certain value of `y`.
2. Your program never stops because you didn't specify a condition on `main_program` in the loop.
3. *(Personnal view)* Every time the chosen operation is done, the program should allow the user to select the new operation he wants to do.

Below is the modified code that I used and it works fine:

```
# This program works only for positive values
main_program = True
def program():
    print('Hello user, please note that this program works only for positive values.')
    print('select 1 to find the sum of two number')
    print('select 2 to find the product two number')
    print('select 3 to raise a number to a power')
    print('select 4 to find the reminder two number')
    print('select q for exit')

    choice = input('human select operation: ')
    global main_program
    if(choice == '1'):
        print(sum_of_numbers())

    elif(choice == '2'):
        print(product_of_numbers(*get_information())-1)
    
    elif(choice == '3'):
        print(esponent_of_numbers(*get_information()))

    elif(choice == '4'):
        modulo_of_numbers(*get_information())

    elif(choice == 'q'):
        print('program terminated')
        main_program = False
    else:
        print('wrong value entered')


def get_information():
    while True:
        try:
            x = float(input('human enter first value: '))
            y = float(input('human enter second value: '))
            return x, y
        except ValueError:
            print('my processors cannot understand the inputs')


def sum_of_numbers():
    x, y = get_information()
    return x + y

def product_of_numbers(x, y):
    if(x < y):
        return product_of_numbers(y, x)
    if(x == 0):
        print('first value is equal to 0, result:', x*y)
        return 1
    else:
        if y==0:
            print('End of calculation')
            return 1
        else:
            res = x + product_of_numbers(x, y-1)
            return res

def esponent_of_numbers(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        print('End of calculation')
        return 1
    elif y % 2 == 0:
        res = esponent_of_numbers(x, y / 2)**2
        return res
    else:
        res = x * esponent_of_numbers(x, y-1)
        return res

def modulo_of_numbers(x, y):
    if x<y:
        print('End of calculation')
        print('The result is: ', x)
        return 1
    if y < x:
        res = modulo_of_numbers(x - y, y)
        return res

while main_program==True:
    program()
```

You encourage to treat the case of negative values in `product_of_numers` and `modulo_of_numbers`. Add constraints on users entries for these two or something like that.

**Best of luck**